# How to customize action for an input field in nested field in rails_admin?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have a model that has a nested field.

```rb
class Contract < ApplicationRecord
...
  has_many :contract_tracks
  has_many :tracks, -> { distinct }, through: :contract_tracks
  has_many :releases, -> { distinct }, through: :contract_tracks
...
```

I need to customize the action on the `tracks` field - I need to display a related `Artist` name together with the Track name, and only on this input.

How can I achieve it?

I went through the [source](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/9abc1be0c1fee006a7a746583461891911fe9330/app/helpers/rails_admin/form_builder.rb) and found that in the end it boils down to `field.render`.
That's quite a long way to override.

Is there something that I can do replicating [this partial _form_nested_many.html.haml](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/9abc1be0c1fee006a7a746583461891911fe9330/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_nested_many.html.haml)?

```
.controls.col-sm-10{data: { nestedmany: true }}
  .btn-group
    %a.btn.btn-info.toggler{:'data-toggle' => "button", :'data-target' => "#{form.jquery_namespace(field)} > .tab-content, #{form.jquery_namespace(field)} > .controls > .nav", class: (field.active? ? 'active' : '')}
      %i.icon-white
    - unless field.nested_form[:update_only] || !field.inline_add
      = form.link_to_add "<i class=\"icon-plus icon-white\"></i> #{wording_for(:link, :new, field.associated_model_config.abstract_model)}".html_safe, field.name, { class: 'btn btn-info' }
  = form.errors_for(field)
  = form.help_for(field)
  %ul.nav.nav-tabs

.tab-content
  = form.fields_for field.name do |nested_form|
    - if field.nested_form[:allow_destroy] || nested_form.options[:child_index] == "new_#{field.name}"
      = nested_form.link_to_remove '<span class="btn btn-small btn-danger"><i class="icon-trash icon-white"></i></span>'.html_safe
    = nested_form.generate({action: :nested, model_config: field.associated_model_config, nested_in: field })
```

Thank you.

---

UPDATE 1

I'm looking into adding a related `Artist` name to be displayed together with `Track` (they are related as many-to-many). And I only need to display it in this certain location.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify what kind of extra data, if you just want to customize the name displayed on each record:
By default rails admin uses the name attribute of an instance to display them.
But i think is better practice to give them their own rails admin specific name as often you'll want the name to be relevant to your operations team and not necessarily to your end users,

With that said you can tell rails admin what method to use adding this line on the initializer config file.

```
RailsAdmin.config {|c| c.label_methods << :rails_admin_title }
```

And then you would implement that instance method on your tag model

```
class Tag < ApplicationRecord
   def rails_admin_title
      "#{self.name} #{self.id}"
   end 
end
```

UPDATE

I'm assuming you want to display this custom name when editing a Contract on the admin only and not on all the other places where a track is displayed on the admin.

If you don't have it defined you'll need to define the edit block with all the fields you wan't in it. And override a method used to get the name of the associated track.

```
class Contract < ApplicationRecord
  rails_admin do
    edit do
      # ... all your other fields you want to add
      field :tracks do
        def associated_object_label_method
          :admin_name_on_contract
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And then define that method

```
class Track < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :artists

  def admin_name_on_contract
    "#{self.name} #{artists.map(&:name).join(',')}"
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Guillermo!
I'm looking into adding a related `Artist` name to be displayed together with `Track` (they are related as many-to-many). And I only need to display it in this certain location. (added to the question)

Comment: Thank you for an update Guillermo! I'll try it a bit later, looks like something I was looking for.

Comment: Well, it seems that it doesn't help, maybe since `tracks` is not referenced directly, but as a part of complex `contract_tracks` field.

Comment: the through: :contract_tracks is only used to create the table join to get the tracks but the actual Track model is used, could you post the error you get?

Comment: I did not get any error, it just did not pickup the method, still displayed the track label only.

Comment: You might have another rails admin config block for the Track model on an initializer so it won't pick up the one on the model class.